# DNS , NS and Mail Server configuration for website hosted on Amazon EC2

Tags: networking, email, dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I created amazon free micro instance on EC2. And hosted my website on that server.

IP like - 52.24.220.140

Problem is that , my domain registrar is Directi.com and I don't have mail hosting also .

Now see what I want

[image]

1. Point my domain to server.
2. Also want use mail hosting which provide by live.com or hotmail.com.

My question where is need to configuration on DNS or NS ?
or 
Where I need to do mail hosting settings ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have purchased your domain (xyz.com) from Directi.com you can create a DNS A record at Directi.com to point www.xyz.com (for example) to 52.24.220.140

For the email setup, you need to setup an MX record at Directi.com
MX records are used for email servers.  You will need to configure your MX record to point to hotmail or windows live.  I've never actually done this myself, but I understand that you will need to register your xyz.com with Windows Live here - https://domains.live.com/ this should then take you through a wizard which will then tell you what details you need to put in your MX record at Directi.com